# Business Intelligence: Data mining with MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, business-intelligence, data-mining

I have to study about data mining using SQL Server. As I know, Business Intelligence in SQL Server supports data mining, but I'm not pretty sure.

- Does BI really support data mining?
- How can I start with data mining with SQL Server? I mean, resources such as books, blogs,..etc

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest beginning your research by focusing on SQL Server Analysis Services via the Books Online Documentation, in particular the "Analysis Services Information Worker InfoCenter" as the information presented is mostly for the attention of data analysts.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174577(SQL.90).aspx

Using the reference you can choose further readying into specific subjects such as "Data Mining Concepts", which will subsequently lead you onto the various Data Mining Algorithms that are available to you.

Then to get hands on with the technology, take a look at the Microsoft Data Mining Tutorial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167167.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Every database supports [data mining](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datamining).  Handling large amounts of structured data is what databases do!

First learn SQL which is useful in many applications and databases.

Then, if you find stuff you can't solve with SQL, you can turn to:

- Reporting services: to create fancy reports
- Analysis services: to analyse truly gigantic amounts of data (if you're thinking in millions of rows, Analysis server is overkill)
- Integration Services: import from non Sql Server sources, automate tasks, combine queries graphically

These are Sql Server specific, and not as useful in every BI scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft BI stack is composed of:

- SQL Server Reporting Services
- SQL Server Analysis Services
- SQL Services Integration Services

The combination of three will allow you to mine data, perform analytics and display them interactively.

I have bookmarked a few good links in my delicious account:

http://delicious.com/syalam/ssrs

Answer (score 0):

Check thislink out - I learned from those screencasts:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/denis_gobo/archive/2007/12/13/3937.aspx